# Scikit learn + Pandas ValueError: shapes (1,1) and (10,10) not aligned

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a problem with SciKit Learn.

I'm doing a really simple linear regression problem. Based on input values of Hours Studied & the resulting grade, I want to be able to estimate a students grade, based on how long they study.

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
In [2]: path = 'Desktop/hoursgrades.csv'
In [3]: df = pd.read_csv(path)
In [4]: X = df['Hours Studied']
In [5]:  y = df['Grade']
In [6]: training_data_in = list() 
In [7]: training_data_out = list()
In [8]: training_data_in.append(X)
In [9]: training_data_out.append(y)  
In [11]: from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
In [12]: model = LinearRegression(n_jobs =-1) 
In [13]: model.fit(X = training_data_in, y = training_data_out)
Out[13]: LinearRegression(copy_X=True, fit_intercept=True, n_jobs=-1, normalize=False)
```

In this example, the DF looks like this:

```
In [16]: df
Out[16]: 
   Hours Studied  Grade
0              1   10.0
1              2   20.0
2              3   30.0
3              4   40.0
4              5   50.0
5              6   60.0
6              7   70.0
7              8   80.0
8              9   90.0
9             10  100.0
```

And X looks like this:

```
In [17]: X
Out[17]: 
0     1
1     2
2     3
3     4
4     5
5     6
6     7
7     8
8     9
9    10
Name: Hours Studied, dtype: int64
```

And y looks like this:

```
In [18]: y
Out[18]: 
0     10.0
1     20.0
2     30.0
3     40.0
4     50.0
5     60.0
6     70.0
7     80.0
8     90.0
9    100.0
Name: Grade, dtype: float64
```

So far so good, it seems to have accepted everything I've put in so far. So now, I want to test the model with some input data. So, I want to say, the number of hours this student studied is 5 & for the model to tell me the expected grade.

But when I put that into the model, I get the below error.

Can anyone advise?

```
In [14]: studied_hour = [[5]]

In [15]: outcome = model.predict(X = studied_hour)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-6fdab4ae2efd> in <module>()
----> 1 outcome = model.predict(X = studied_hour)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/base.py in predict(self, X)
    254             Returns predicted values.
    255         """
--> 256         return self._decision_function(X)
    257 
    258     _preprocess_data = staticmethod(_preprocess_data)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/base.py in _decision_function(self, X)
    239         X = check_array(X, accept_sparse=['csr', 'csc', 'coo'])
    240         return safe_sparse_dot(X, self.coef_.T,
--> 241                                dense_output=True) + self.intercept_
    242 
    243     def predict(self, X):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/extmath.py in safe_sparse_dot(a, b, dense_output)
    138         return ret
    139     else:
--> 140         return np.dot(a, b)
    141 
    142 

ValueError: shapes (1,1) and (10,10) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 10 (dim 0)
```

I should add:

```
In [39]: X.shape
Out[39]: (10,)

In [40]: y.shape
Out[40]: (10,)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input shape of both `X` and `y` is not correct, it has to be `(n_samples, n_features`) for `X` and `(n_samples,)` for `y` as per the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html).

You see the error because the model thinks you have ten features and ten different outputs (hence the (10, 10)).

You get the correct results by using

```
X = df[['Hours Studied']]  # note the double brackets, shape (10, 1)
y = df['Grade']
model = LinearRegression().fit(X, y)

model.predict([[5]])
array([50.])
```

Comment: Thank you!! - can you give me any more explanation on why the double brackets are required on the definiton of X?

Comment: @kikee1222 It's for selecting a list of columns (here of length 1), so that the selection yields a data frame instead of a series (2d array instead of 1d).